# Explain the steps to upgrade DD4T 1.0.3 to DD4T 2.0 9

Tags: sdl-tridion

I'm new to SDL Trdion group. Please explain the step by step process that needs to be done in both CM
(SDL web 8) and CD side while upgrading DD4T 1.0.3 to DD4T 2.0

Comment: What have you researched and read? What have you tried?

Comment: you can refer the blog post updated in the answer

Answer (score 3):

I hope you have done some research and ask specific question, although I would answer you as I am currently writing a detailed blog post series on this.

On a high level, you would be doing following:

**CM Side**

- Download and install the DD4T TBB setup on your CM server following the instructions provided on www.dd4t.org - Do Not try to overwrite the existing TBBs of older DD4T version
- Changes the reference in all your CTs and PTs for using these updated TBBs
- Try Publishing the content (page and component) using these new TBBs and ensure it is publishing successfully.

NOTE: DD4T 2.0 does not (at the time of writing this) support to XML and only renders the JSON output - This means if you have any customization in TBBs or if you are using a custom TBB along with DD4T TBBs to make a compound template - Well you may need to rewrite all those TBBs

**CD Side:**

- Remove references to older DD4T dlls
- Download and Install the DD4T 2.0 packages using NuGet Manager
- Ensure your project is using references to these new dlls
- Compile the project - You would be presented with few hundreds of compile errors due to various changes in the framework - work on to resolve these compile errors
- Once compiled try to run your project - you may come across few run time error - this depends on your existing code and mostly due to new dependencies introduced which you may need to define in your DI framework
- DD4T 2.0 is known to be backward compatible and should be working with your previously published items in XML format but this is something you should test
- Publish your new items in JSON format and test your code

NOTE: The number and resolution of compile time errors and run time errors depends on a variety of factors including how much customization of DD4T features have been done

All the best.

**UPDATE**

You can now refer these blog post related to my experience while upgrading to DD4T:

- [Overview](https://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/2016/04/15/upgrade-to-dd4t-2-0-overview/)
- [Content Delivery](https://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/2016/04/15/upgrade-to-dd4t-2-0-content-delivery-cd/)
- [Content Manager](https://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/2016/05/29/upgrade-to-dd4t-2-0-content-manager-cm/)